# The "dagre" utility is a mandatory dependency

Tags: reactjs, jointjs, dagre

I am using jointjs and to auto layout the nodes I am using dagre library. my code break at this line

```
joint.layout.DirectedGraph.layout(self.graph, {
        setLinkVertices: false,
        rankDir: "LR",
        rankSep: 150,
        marginX: 100,
        marginY: 200,
        nodeSep: 80,
        edgeSep: 50
      }
      );
```

showing me  Error: The the "dagre" utility is a mandatory dependency.
I am using  dagre@0.7.3 and jointjs@3.0.4,

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same issue. The jointjs DirectedGraph plugin requires the dagre and graphlib packages.

To get around this I npm installed both dagre and graphlib.

So you would need to do this...

```
import dagre from 'dagre';
import graphlib from 'graphlib';
import * as joint from 'jointjs';

joint.layout.DirectedGraph.layout(self.graph, {
    dagre: dagre,
    graphlib: graphlib
    setLinkVertices: false,
    rankDir: "LR",
    rankSep: 150,
    marginX: 100,
    marginY: 200,
    nodeSep: 80,
    edgeSep: 50
  }
  );
```

Comment: I didn't notice initially, but also include the `dagre` and `graphlib` in the `LayoutOptions` passed to the `layout` function.